# Fixed point button using absolute layout not responding to events

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a listview on a content page. I have placed a fixed point button(think that is proper name) on the page using AvsoluteLayout. I have the button going to the top of the view using RaiseChild. The click event is not firing on the button but on the list view.

my on appearing where bubblebutton is the item at issue

````
 

    protected override void OnAppearing()
            {
                base.OnAppearing();
                IsBusy = true;
                if(viewModel.PlayerActivities == null)
                {
                    viewModel.LoadPlayerActivites.Execute(null);
                }
                IsBusy = false;
                
                grid.RaiseChild(bubblebutton);
                bubblebutton.Clicked += Bubblebutton_Clicked;
            }
    
    
    ```
    
    ```
     <AbsoluteLayout  >
                    
                    <ImageButton x:Name="bubblebutton" 
                        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                        Source="st_fab_button.png"
                        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="3,500,700,80" 
                                
                        Clicked="bubblebutton_Clicked"
                        IsEnabled="True"
                    />               
    </AbsoluteLayout>
    ```

[button click is not happening][1]

Thank you for any help sorry for poor clip art skill


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJixO.png
````

Comment: Welcome to SO ! This can not fired by using `x:Name` in `ListView` . You should use binding Command to get the click event of `Button` .

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO !

If using `Button` inside `Item` of `ListView` , should use the **MVVM** architecture to do . That means we should use Binding model to get the click event .

Such as modified code as follow :

````
```
 <AbsoluteLayout  >
                
                <ImageButton x:Name="bubblebutton" 
                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                    Source="st_fab_button.png"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="3,500,700,80" 
                            
                    Command="{Binding MyCommand}"
                    IsEnabled="True"
                />               
</AbsoluteLayout>
```
````

Then in your **ViewModle** should declare the `MyCommand` :

```
public ICommand MyCommand { private set; get; }

public ViewModel()
{
    MyCommand = new Command(
        execute: () =>
        {
           // do some thing
            RefreshCanExecutes();
        },
        canExecute: () =>
        {
           // return !IsEditing;
        });

    ···

}
```

In addition , you also can pass **Parameters**  , more info can have a look at this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/commanding#the-icommand-interface) .